# Jackson ObjectMapper - How to configure to not use a custom Json Serializer

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I am working on a project which has a custom JSON Serializer defined

```
public class JsonCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<CustomObject> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(
            CustomObject customObject,
            JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
            SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
                // custom implementation
            }
}
```

I am using an `ObjectMapper` and invoking `writeValueAsString(Object)` method. This invokes the custom implementation as defined using the class  `JsonCustomSerializer`. How can I configure `ObjectMapper` to not use the `JsonCustomSerializer`? The custom serializer is used by another instance of ObjectMapper in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure `ObjectMapper` to ignore your custom serializer for a specific class, you can use the `SimpleModule` class provided by Jackson. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Create a SimpleModule
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();

        // Disable the custom serializer for CustomObject class
        simpleModule.addSerializer(CustomObject.class, new CustomObjectDefaultSerializer());

        // Register the module with the ObjectMapper
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

        // Now, when you use this objectMapper, it won't use your custom serializer for CustomObject

        // Your code here...
    }
}
```